# Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I get the following notification in phpMyadmin

> Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.

Below is the query I ran in phpMyadmin. I have tried using on instead of Using and I have also tried removing some of the joins. The minute I uses INNER JOIN I get the notification.

I have tried to find solutions but they all involve setting an index or AI for a column

```
SELECT    mr.response_id, mr.user_id, mr.topic_id, mr.response,
                mt.name AS topic_name, mt.category_id,
                mu.username, mc.name AS category_name
     FROM       mismatch_response AS mr
     INNER JOIN mismatch_topic AS mt USING(topic_id)
     INNER JOIN mismatch_user AS mu USING(user_id)
     INNER JOIN mismatch_category AS mc USING(category_id)
```

but in all tables I have a column that is set as the primary key with Auto increment.

Not sure what else to do

Answer (score 1):

Your all the tables might have a column as Primary Key with Auto Increment. But the result you get after executing the above query doesn't have any unique index.

All the operations i.e. Edit, Copy and Delete require a Unique Index to work, obviously you wont want all your data delete on just deleting a single data row.

Comment: How do I correct this or make one with a Unique index?

Comment: Add a unique index from any one table in the `SELECT` statement..remember ONLY ONE table

Comment: Inshort..in the result set..only one Primary Key should be there.. If using JOINS, let the Primary Key be from anytable

Comment: Thank you. How do I do that, can you give me an example with the query I used? Or do you lose it once tyou use multiple joins?

Comment: I changes it to the following so that there was only one column was a primary key and I got the same                                                                           SELECT  mr.response, mt.name AS topic_name,
                mu.username, mc.name AS category_name
     FROM       mismatch_response AS mr
     INNER JOIN mismatch_topic AS mt USING(topic_id)
     INNER JOIN mismatch_user AS mu USING(user_id)
     INNER JOIN mismatch_category AS mc USING(category_id)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if you use JOIN in query, phpmyadmin always shows `Current selection does not contain a unique column.` and disable ability to edit row. :(
I tried to create 2 simple table t1 and t2. Both of them have two fields: 'id' as primary autoincrement and 'name'.

All my queries are outputting the message `Current selection does not contain a unique column.`:

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.* FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.name=t2.name;
SELECT t1.id,t1.name FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.name=t2.name;
SELECT t1.id,t1.name FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id;
```

But if I create a `view` for this query, the rows become editable in phpmyadmin.